# How can I prevent open tabs with YouTube videos from playing after Windows 10 restarts?

Tags: youtube, google-chrome, windows, autoplay

I have several tabs open with YouTube videos, in several windows. This is on Chrome, Windows 10.

I know that if I sleep the computer, everything will come back OK.
But if I log out of Windows, Chrome will be shut down.  When I log in again, Chrome will restore all the tabs but start many of the videos playing, especially those in the showing tab of each open window.

How can I keep those from playing?

I already have "AUTOPLAY" off.  That's not the problem.

Comment: Is "use Firefox instead" an option? Firefox doesn't load a page till you actually open the tab.

Answer (score 0):

But that's still the problem. Not all "autoplay off" switches can do what they should. Try **[Iridium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/iridium-for-youtube/gbjmgndncjkjfcnpfhgidhbgokofegbl)**.

[image: 0]

---

If you often just leave open your tabs for laters (which never comes) try **[Suspender](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-great-suspender/klbibkeccnjlkjkiokjodocebajanakg)** which is able to completely freeze tabs and free RAM resources.

---

Also, you can run experiments in **`chrome://flags/`**:

[image]